# Creating several millions of relationships in Neo4j takes a very long time

Tags: .net, csv, neo4j

I am using the latest Neo4j.Driver package (4.2.0) and the latest community edition of the Neo4j server (4.2.3).

I must be doing something wrong, because my query takes hours to complete.

I have 4 CSV files:

1. XyzTypes.csv - defines 96,328 type nodes.
2. XyzMethods.csv - defines 975,507 methods across all the types.
3. XyzTypeTypeDependencies.csv - defines 121,834 type-type DEPENDS_ON relationships.
4. XyzTypeMethods.csv - defines 973,972 type-method DECLARES relationships.

The following code should be very simple. It just needs to load all the CSV and create the respective Types, Methods and the relationships.

Here is my code:

```cs
var driver = GraphDatabase.Driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.Basic("neo4j", "1"));
var session = driver.AsyncSession(o => o.WithDatabase("neo4j"));
try
{
    Console.Write("[DI");
    await session.RunAsync("DROP INDEX type_id_index IF EXISTS");
    await session.RunAsync("DROP INDEX method_id_index IF EXISTS");

    Console.Write("][C");
    await session.WriteTransactionAsync(async tx =>
    {
        await tx.RunAsync("match ()-[r]->() delete r");
        await tx.RunAsync("match (n) delete n");
        return default(object);
    });

    Console.Write("][T");
    await session.WriteTransactionAsync(async tx =>
    {
        await tx.RunAsync(@"
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Temp/XyzTypes.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Type {
    typeId: toInteger(line.id),
    name: line.name,
    fullName: line.fullName,
    isCompilerGenerated: toBoolean(line.isCompilerGenerated),
    asmName: line.asmName
})");
        return default(object);
    });

    Console.Write("][M");
    await session.WriteTransactionAsync(async tx =>
    {
        await tx.RunAsync(@"
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Temp/XyzMethods.csv' AS line
CREATE (:Method {
    methodId: toInteger(line.id),
    name: line.name,
    fullName: line.fullName,
    isCompilerGenerated: toBoolean(line.isCompilerGenerated)
})");
        return default(object);
    });

    Console.Write("][CI");
    await session.RunAsync("CREATE INDEX type_id_index FOR (t:Type) ON (t.typeId)");
    await session.RunAsync("CREATE INDEX method_id_index FOR (m:Method) ON (m.methodId)");
    
    Console.Write("][TT");
    await session.RunAsync(@"
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Temp/XyzTypeTypeDependencies.csv' AS line
MATCH (src:Type), (dst:Type)
WHERE src.typeId = toInteger(line.src) AND dst.typeId = toInteger(line.dst)
CREATE (src)-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(dst)
");

    Console.Write("][TM");
    await session.RunAsync(@"
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Temp/XyzTypeMethods.csv' AS line
MATCH (src:Type), (dst:Method)
WHERE src.typeId = toInteger(line.src) AND dst.methodId = toInteger(line.dst)
CREATE (src)-[:DECLARES]->(dst)
");

    Console.Write("] ... ");
}
finally
{
    await session.CloseAsync();
    await driver.CloseAsync();
}
```

The `CREATE INDEX` queries return immediately. Could be legit, I do not know how fast Neo4j can index a number property in about 1M nodes. Running `:schema` in the browser confirms the two indices, but I have a feeling they are not working.

Running the above code takes almost 3 hours. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT 1**

So I changed the last two queries to use the `MERGE` clause:

```cs
    Console.Write("][TT");
    await session.RunAsync(@"
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Temp/XyzTypeTypeDependencies.csv' AS line
MERGE (src:Type {typeId: toInteger(line.src)})-[:DEPENDS_ON]->(dst:Type {typeId: toInteger(line.dst)})
");
    
    Console.Write("][TM");
    await session.RunAsync(@"
USING PERIODIC COMMIT LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///C:/Temp/XyzTypeMethods.csv' AS line
MERGE (src:Type {typeId: toInteger(line.src)})-[:DECLARES]->(dst:Method {methodId: toInteger(line.dst)})
");
```

It is supposed to be much better now, because I think what I did before caused cartesian multiplication between the nodes. Yet the last query is taking an unknown amount of time (no idea how long at the moment) - still bad.

Comment: Index and constraint creation is asynchronous, so you're likely jumping the gun before the indexes and constraints are up. You should probably use `CALL db.awaitIndexes()` just in case. Also, the MERGE approach isn't recommended, as it has to check if such a pattern exists and if not create the whole pattern, which will end up duplicating nodes. MATCHing on the nodes, then either CREATE or MERGE the relationship, is the better approach (only MERGE if the rel might already exist). Ignore the cartesian product warning, that's exactly what you need (1 x 1 per row) to create the relationship.

Comment: So basically, you are telling me to go back to the version before **EDIT 1**. I will and add awaiting for the indices.

Comment: @InverseFalcon - please, arrange your comment as an answer, so I could credit you, because it works! I guess `db.awaitIndexes` is the key. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index and constraint creation is asynchronous, so you're likely jumping the gun before the indexes and constraints are up. You should probably use `CALL db.awaitIndexes()` just in case.

Also, the MERGE approach isn't recommended, as it has to check if such a pattern exists and if not create the whole pattern, which will end up duplicating nodes. MATCHing on the nodes, then either CREATE or MERGE the relationship, is the better approach (only MERGE if the rel might already exist, or if the same nodes might be matched on multiple rows for the given input data).

Ignore the cartesian product warning, that's exactly what you need (1 x 1 per row) to create the relationship.